# SAPUI5 Calendar problem with Date, one day forward?

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I got some problems with my calendar.
Maybe you can help me?

First of all I got the calendar from class: sap.m.Calendar
and when I fire the 'onClick' function, it shows me the wrong data.

For example, I got data for 06-09-2018. When I click on the 6th it shows no data. But when I click on the 7th, it shows the data from the 6th. 
So very confusing..

In a nutshell, it shows me the data in for the wrong date. 07-09-2018 shows in 08-09-2018 ... and so on.

**My calendar in the view:**

```
<l:fixContent>
    <me:Calendar id="WEEKLY_CALENDAR" swipeToNavigate="true" design="Approval" 
                 singleRow="true" weeksPerRow="2" hideNavControls="false"
                 tapOnDate="onSelect"></me:Calendar>
</l:fixContent>
```

**My Items in the view :**

```
<Table id="ProjList" items="{/ZCATSDBSet}" noDataText="Keine Daten für diesen Tag">
    <columns>
        <Column hAlign="Left">
            <Text text="Projekt Aufgabe"/>
        </Column>
        <Column hAlign="Center">
            <Text class="Dauer" text="Dauer"/>
        </Column >
        <Column >
            <Text textAlign="Left" text="Kurzbeschreibung"/>
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem id="objectList" type="Navigation" press="onPressToEdit">
            <cells>
                <Text id="Name2" text="{Rproj}"/>
                <Text id="Dauer2" text="{Catshours}"/>
                <Text text="{Ltxa1}"/>
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

**and my `toponDate="onSelect"` function**

```
onSelect: function(oEvent) {
    //FILTERT BEIM KLICKEN (DIE PORJEKTLISTE)
    //Filtert nach dem Datum und setzt die neuen Daten

    var that = this;
    var sDate = oEvent.getParameter("date");
    var aFilters = [];
    var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("Workdate", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, sDate);
    aFilters.push(oFilter);
    var oTable = this.getView().byId("ProjList");
    var oBinding = oTable.getBinding("items");
    oBinding.filter(aFilters);
    oTable.bindElement({
        path: "/ZCATSDBSet",
        template: null, // columnTemplate
        filters: aFilters
    });
}
```

The Debugger says that the oEvent Date is right. So I don't know what to do

so maybe you can help me? Sorry for my bad english :P

Comment: It may be a timezone issue. Germany currently is 2 hours ahead of UTC (e.g. 07.09.2018 0:00 UTC +2 is 06.09.2018 22:00 +0, UTC). SAP cuts of the timezone information and just sees 060920182200 so it thinks that's what you want. You can manually subtract the timezone offset (`date.getTimezoneOffset()`).

Comment: Have you seen that the `sap.me` version has been deprecated? `Deprecated as of version 1.26.0. This control was experimental since 1.12. Please use the sap.ui.unified.Calendar instead!`.

Comment: @Jorg yeah i saw it.. but there is problem with all of these.. and I need the design of this one.. the other "calendar" are just datepickers.. thats not the point of my projekt..

Comment: @Marc Hey marc, first of all thanks.. but i try it already... the oEvent while im clicklig is according to debugger right.. its the right Time with UTC + . But i found something and maybe it is the problem..
the Odata data which i recive is like this: 
 Workdate: Thu Sep 06 2018 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit), …}

and the onclick event ist like :
sDate = "Fri Sep 06 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)" 
if you compare the data from the backend is with 02:00:00 maybe this is the problem?

Comment: i had a similar issue, convertig the date solved my problem: var oValue = <your_DateObject>;  new Date(Date.UTC(oValue.getFullYear(), oValue.getMonth(), oValue.getDate()));

Comment: yeah @Medera i done it but, the backend got the standard sap date. But i got a solution. I have in sap a table where i write the date in a string like "20180515" and than convert it into the new date() for my data. Also you need format your date in the controller befor you create a new entity